# Using Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) to find users by post count and reputation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017, dataexplorer

I want to find out which users have the most reputation with the least amount of posts (less than 10). But why can't I have a `where` clause before this join? :

```
SELECT TOP 100 Users.Id, Users.DisplayName AS [Username], Users.Reputation, COUNT(Posts.Id) AS [Post Count] FROM Users
//WHERE COUNT(Posts.Id) < 10
JOIN Posts ON Posts.OwnerUserId = Users.Id 
GROUP BY Users.Id, Users.DisplayName, Users.Reputation
ORDER BY Users.Reputation DESC;
```

The original user post count example query is at [data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/503051](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/503051/user-post-count-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what [the `HAVING` clause](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-having-sql-tutorial/) ([MS reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) is for.

You would use:

```
SELECT TOP 100 Users.Id, Users.DisplayName AS [Username], Users.Reputation, COUNT(Posts.Id) AS [Post Count] FROM Users
JOIN Posts ON Posts.OwnerUserId = Users.Id
GROUP BY Users.Id, Users.DisplayName, Users.Reputation
HAVING COUNT(Posts.Id) < 10
ORDER BY Users.Reputation DESC;
```

But here it is, leveraging a few [SEDE features](https://data.stackexchange.com/help):

```
-- maxRows: How many rows to return:
-- maxPosts: Maximum number of posts a user can have:

SELECT TOP ##maxRows:INT?100##
            'site://u/' + CAST(u.Id AS NVARCHAR) + '|' + u.DisplayName  AS [User]
            , u.Reputation
            , COUNT (p.Id)  AS [Post Count]
FROM        Users u
LEFT JOIN   Posts p         ON (p.OwnerUserId = u.Id  AND  p.PostTypeId IN (1, 2) )  -- Q & A only
GROUP BY    u.Id
            , u.DisplayName
            , u.Reputation
HAVING      COUNT (p.Id) <= ##maxPosts:INT?10##
ORDER BY    u.Reputation DESC
            , [Post Count]
            , u.DisplayName
```

You can [**see it live in SEDE**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/919052/users-with-max-reputation-by-n-number-of-posts?maxRows=100&maxPosts=10).

I particularly like [the users with higher rep that have no posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/919052/users-with-max-reputation-by-n-number-of-posts?maxRows=100&maxPosts=0).